# PCL and SQLite (with IDbConnection and so on)

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

in my application all the data will be stored in SQLite database. But I would also like to be able to store them in MySQL (MariaDB).

My application also will be multiplatform. So I started creating CORE as PCL. I am using interfaces like IDbConnection, IDbTransaction and so on.

But unfortunately all SQLite implementations for PCL that I've found are not using these interfaces.

Does anyone know about SQLite PCL implementation that implements database interfaces?

For example SQLiteConnection should derive from DbConnection.

Comment: PCL (printer language) or Portable Class Library?

Comment: Portable Class Library

Comment: Then you should double check your tags, since `printer-control-language` should instead be `portable-class-library`.

Comment: Oh, now I see what stack does. When I type PCL it changes to printer-control-language :|

Comment: I didn't know PCL supports these interfaces at all - but if it does you could have platform-specific startup code that creates the XxSql connections and passes them to the PCL by interface, so your PCLs don't have to worry about their implementation details.

Comment: It's not the case. I want to have SQLite and MySQL and other DBs in my PCL. Client code (for example Android or Windows Forms) has only to call a method from my PCL and PCL saves data to database.

Comment: @AdamJachocki, were you able to sort this out? I am in the same situation with SQLite-net